# Golang regex exact line in file

Tags: regex, linux, bash, go

I have a file with below content

```
# Requires authentication with auth-user-pass
auth-user-pass
#auth-user-pass
# auth-user-pass
auth-user-passwd
```

Is there any way to regex only match the second line with Golang?

I have tried with following code but it return empty slice

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    bytes, err := os.ReadFile("file.txt")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    re, _ := regexp.Compile(`^auth-user-pass$`)
    matches := re.FindAllString(string(bytes), -1)
    fmt.Println(matches)
}
```

```
$ go run main.go
[]
```

Comment: Sure, `grep --help`, `man grep` and `info grep`

Comment: I just edited the question to make it clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string contains multiple lines, so you should turn on the [multiline mode](https://pkg.go.dev/regexp/syntax) (with the `m` flag) :

Here is a quick example :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    var str = `# Requires authentication with auth-user-pass
auth-user-pass
#auth-user-pass
# auth-user-pass
auth-user-passwd`

    re, _ := regexp.Compile(`(?m)^auth-user-pass$`)
    matches := re.FindAllString(str, -1)
    fmt.Println(matches)
}
```

You can try this snippet on : https://play.golang.com/p/6au1_K2ImBt.